# How to prevent Django from renaming key column in model with managed=False?

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle

I have two models in Django with managed=False, because they are generated by SQL.

Django's Querysets based on these models do not generate the SQL queries they should. They add an '_ID' suffix to a column name that I never specified. This causes the queries to fail.

The models:

```
class MaterialsPerBatch(models.Model):
    BATCH = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    MATERIAL = models.ForeignKey('ColumnsPerMaterialStatic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"
        managed = False


class ColumnsPerMaterialStatic(models.Model):
    MATERIAL = models.CharField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=255)
    MATERIAL_LINK = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "CDH_COL_PER_MAT_STATIC"
        managed = False
```

I want to filter the first model by BATCH, and find all corresponding second models that share the MATERIAL field.

The query looks like this:

```
qs = models.MaterialsPerBatch.objects.filter(
        BATCH__in=['foo', 'bar']).values('BATCH', 'MATERIAL__MATERIAL_LINK')
```

I get this error: "django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"."MATERIAL_ID": invalid identifier"

Inspecting qs.query shows that Django runs the following query in the background:

```
SELECT "CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"."BATCH", "CDH_COL_PER_MAT_STATIC"."MATERIAL_LINK"
FROM "CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"
INNER JOIN "CDH_COL_PER_MAT_STATIC"
ON ("CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"."MATERIAL_ID" = "CDH_COL_PER_MAT_STATIC"."MATERIAL")
WHERE "CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"."BATCH" IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

So the question is, why does Django turn "CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"."MATERIAL" into "CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"."MATERIAL_ID"?

I never specified any '_ID' suffix.

How do I tell Django not to add that suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django allows the `db_column` name to be specified, so it will not assume the `_id` is part of the name.

```
class MaterialsPerBatch(models.Model):
    BATCH = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255, db_column='BATCH')
    MATERIAL = models.ForeignKey('ColumnsPerMaterialStatic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH"
        managed = False


class ColumnsPerMaterialStatic(models.Model):
    MATERIAL = models.CharField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length=255, db_column='MATERIAL')
    MATERIAL_LINK = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "CDH_COL_PER_MAT_STATIC"
        managed = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify the name of the column with the [**`db_column=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column):

```
class MaterialsPerBatch(models.Model):
    BATCH = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    MATERIAL = models.ForeignKey(
        'ColumnsPerMaterialStatic',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='MATERIAL'
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CDH_MATERIALS_PER_BATCH'
        managed = False
```

Normally the names of the fields are written in *snake_case*, not *SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE*, so you might want to consider renaming `BATCH` and `MATERIAL` to `batch` and `material` and thus use the `db_column` to specify the name of the database column:

```
class MaterialsPerBatch(models.Model):
    batch = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        db_column='BATCH'
    )
    material = models.ForeignKey(
        'ColumnsPerMaterialStatic',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='MATERIAL'
    )
    
    # …
```